# Using SDL_TTF as a class, memory leak

Tags: c++, text, memory-leaks, sdl, sdl-ttf

I have a huge memory leak which is making me question my implementation of `SDL_TTF` as a whole.

Right now I have the following classes

```
MainMenu
Menu
Options
Button 
Text
```

The `MainMenu` and `Option` classes abstract the menu class and each call their own button class with parameters that build the text class.

So right now my main loop passes the `SDL_Renderer` (gRenderer) down through a MainMenu->Button->Text path.

When my Text class is initialized it loads the font, sets up the font using `TTF_RenderText_Solid` with the message that has been passed in by the Button class, and the `TTF_SetFontStyle` to set the text bold.

I draw using:

```
void Text::draw(SDL_Renderer* gRenderer)
{   
renderQuad = { getXPosition(), getYPosition() };//, getWidth(), getHeight()};   
mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, message);
SDL_RenderCopyEx(gRenderer, mTexture, NULL, 
                    &renderQuad, NULL, NULL,  SDL_FLIP_NONE);
};
```

I believe it is bloating on `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` or `SDL_RenderCopyEx`.

What can I do to amend this memory leak? Am I overlooking something blatant?

Solution:

Discovering/Using Twinklebear's ifnroamtion:

When declaring the object in the header, I declared the texture and set it equal to `NULL` By: `SDL_Texture* mTexture = NULL;`

Then, inside of the draw function I check if the texture is set to NULL or not:

```
void Text::draw(SDL_Renderer* gRenderer)
{    

renderQuad = { getXPosition(), getYPosition(), message->w, message->h };

if (mTexture == NULL)
{
    mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, message);
}

SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, mTexture, NULL, &renderQuad);
};
```

What I would like to do is throw a boolean variable on the class to state if the texture needs updated or not, and reset the texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're calling the draw function each frame you're creating lots of textures but not freeing them, causing your memory leak.

```
mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, message);
```

creates a new texture of the message which you need to free later on with `SDL_DestroyTexture`, if you don't free this texture you'll leak the memory and if you leak a texture every frame it'll start to add up really quick.

To fix this you shouldn't reload the surface into a texture unless you're changing the message displayed since there's no need to re-create the same texture each frame (it's also pretty slow to do this each frame).

Comment: Yeah, it was exactly as you say. I actually made a mistake because of my inexperience with C++ that I will add on to your answer, if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure that's fine. You might also want to pick up a book on C++, memory management is pretty important for games/C++ code in general. There's a good list over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).